# How to build a MOKE (magneto-optic Kerr effect) magnetometer at home?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, home-experiment

I'd like to build a magnetometer at home. The type does not matter actually that much but it should be doable at home. The [MOKE](https://www.physik.uni-kl.de/fileadmin/hillebrands/Equipment/moke1.jpg) (magneto-optic Kerr effect) magnetometer at least *appears* to use relatively simple components.

However, looking at lasers, it seems the price range is really broad. What kind of laser would be precise enough? How about the Wollaston prism? Those are really expensive, easily over 1000 USD. Could I replace it with something cheaper?

I hope the question fits the site. Please note that I'm not a physicist.

Comment: Your polarizing beam splitter does not have to be a Wollaston prism. You should be able to get small (say 5mm) polarizing beam splitter cubes brand new for USD 200 or less (but then you need to make sure you buy for the correct wavelength). They are also a likely component of mass-fabricated CD/DVD drives, but don't count on getting any non-salvaged ones in low volumes. Your real issue will probably be having to understand the magnitude of the effect and the resulting required intensity to get a usable signal, find a suitable laser, and laser safety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find the [Faraday Effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_effect) easier. Since it was actually done by Faraday it is quite easy. You need a glass or plastic rod aligned with the magnetic field you want to measure, a monochromatic or coherent light source, a couple of polarizing filters and a photodiode. The magnetic field rotates the plane of polarization proportional to the field in the transparent medium.

Comment: Any ideas where to obtain polarizing filters of sufficient quality? And the light source..

Comment: Linear polarizing filters off eBay, and a red laser pointer $15 tops.